# How to avoid duplicates when building attributes in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

An XML file contains an unspecified number of unsorted elements with the attribute "art". For each different attribute "art" exactly one value should be entered in the attribute "keywords" as a comma-separated list.

### xml extract

```
...
<records art="abc"/>
<records art="cba"/>
<records art="abc"/>
<records art="bac"/>
<records art="bac"/>
<records art="abc"/>
...
```

### expected result

```
<meta name="keywords" content="abc,cba,bac"/>
```

The XSLT example creates a list entry for each attribute, regardless of whether it has already been entered or not.

### xslt example

```
...
<meta name="keywords">
  <xsl:attribute name="content">
    <xsl:for-each select="records">
      <xsl:value-of select="@art"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:attribute>
</meta>
...
```

I'm looking for an efficient method in XSLT 1.0 that avoids multiple entries and that can be extended to additional attributes if necessary.

Comment: Please search for "eliminating duplicates in XSLT 1.0" or "grouping in XSLT 1.0" and you will find numerous answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Special thanks to Michael Kay (https://www.saxonica.com/) for the hint.*

```
<meta name="keywords">
  <xsl:attribute name="content">
    <xsl:for-each select="//records[not(@art = preceding-sibling::records/@art)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="@art"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:attribute>
</meta>
```

This solution is O(n²). On larger node-sets better use the Muenchian method.